# Finding a dictionary number x in a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, list, csv

I am trying to find a specific dictionary in a list of dictionaries, by using a loop. However I get an error message which is: KeyError: 1

```
def EU():
    wrong = 0
    correct = 0
    for country in eu:
        ans = input("what is the capital of " + country[0][1] + ": ")
        str.lower(ans)
        if ans == country[1][1]:
            print("CORRECT")
            correct = correct + 1
        else:
            print("WRONG. It is: " + country[1][1])
            wrong = wrong + 1

    print("Correct: " + str(correct))
    print("wrong: " + str(wrong))
    print("You got " + str(correct) + " out of 25")

#finding the data from a .csv file

nl = {'newline': ''}
mode = 'r'
if sys.version_info < (3, 0):
    nl.pop('newline', None)
    mode = 'rb'
with open('Europe_Capitals.csv', mode, **nl) as fp:
    reader = csv.reader(fp, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
    # next(reader, None)  # skip the headers
    dr = [row for row in reader]

europe = []

for y in range(0, 51):
    a = {
            "Country" : dr[y][0],
            "Capital" : dr[y][1]
        },
    #print(a)
    if y == 51:
        a = {
            "Country" : dr[y][0],
            "Capital" : dr[y][1]
            }
    europe.append(a)
```

The program is meant to cycle through the capitals of europe and ask me them, but instead I got 'what is the capital of country', and now I just get an error message stating `KeyError: 1`

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) applies here. We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.
You've included superfluous system code, and omitted your data structure.  Don't read a file; just assign your directory.

Comment: Can we see a sample of the data in `Europe_Capitals.csv` ?

Comment: `if y == 51:` This will never be true, since `range(0, 51)` stops at `50`.

Comment: Why do you even need that, since it's the same as the previous assignment of `a`?

Comment: Which line is the error happening on?

Comment: You never call the `EU()` function.

Comment: You shouldn't use binary mode to read a CSV file.

Comment: You shouldn't hard-code the length of the list. Use `europe = [{"Country": country, "Capital": capital} for country, capital in dr[0:2]]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This section

```py
a = {
        "Country" : dr[y][0],
        "Capital" : dr[y][1]
     },    # <-- note the comma
```

is creating a tuple `(dict, None)`

so when you have

```py
for country in eu:
   ...
```

`country` is that same form, a tuple. so `country[0]` gives you the dictionary but it has no key `1` so it throws the key error

you should get rid of the comma at the end of creating `a` (above).

Then, to get the country's name you would use `country["Country"]` and to get the capital use `country["Capital"]`